# When I run terraform plan there is no response, it keeps running

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, terraform-template-file

I just created azure account and tried to create resource group using terraform, I provided `sub.id`, `tenant_id`, `client_id` and `client_secret`. But after terraform init and validate, terraform plan is not responding, will it take long time, should I need to wait or Is it an error?

I tried with gitbash terminal and powershell terminal and I tried with different local directories, it gives the same response. Refer the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srH8t.png) here.

Comment: Can you provide code in the text format? @Aswin kumar

Comment: What error do you see after you cancel (Ctrl+C) the terraform plan command?

Comment: Have you found solution, then dont forget to accept one of the answers as solution.

Answer (score 0):

this indicates a potential issue or delay in the execution though it is difficult to find out the exact reason without more information.

Please check the below steps in case any of these will help:

1. Use this command to enable commands with the debug flag. It will enable debug logging. I think this will provide more information on what Terraform is doing and where it gets stuck.

```css
export TF_LOG=DEBUG 
terraform plan
```

1. Also, double-check check you have proper permissions to create a resource group.
2. Sometimes there might be some network issues or slow Azure API responses and due to that Terraform behaves like it's hanging. Please try adding some timeout.

```css
terraform plan -timeout=2m
```

Comment: yes I waited and saw, the error is "ensure the resource provider is registered", I tried to resolve that by registering microsoft.apicentre in azure portal and still the problem persist

Comment: @Aswinkumar Yeah, classic error! Checkout my answer below.

Comment: @Aswinkumar If you go to the subscription menu, and select "Resource providers", do you see Microsoft ApiManagement registered there? If you find it there then run again terraform init, terraform plan -debug for re-authenticating and see what will happen. It should not give "ensure the resource provider is registered" error again.

Comment: this is what I am getting when I terraform plan -debug   "Error: Failed to parse command-line flags , flag provided but not defined: -debug"

Comment: and other solution is that I need to register micrsoft.web in azure portal, but its not registering, its just spinning in the state of registering but not registered

Comment: @Aswinkumar About this debug flag.. try this one

`export TF_LOG=DEBUG`

then

`terraform plan`

BTW, so this is still happening due to No successful registration. But have you already registered Microsoft ApiManagement?

Comment: yes ApiManagement registered

Comment: Interesting. So what's the error now?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably its due Microsoft Provider(s) not registered. You can either register a provider or set flag `skip_provider_registration`.

```
provider "azurerm" {
  skip_provider_registration = true
}
```

Register a [provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/register-azresourceprovider?view=azps-11.3.0#example-1-register-a-provider), if not already:

```
Register-AzResourceProvider -ProviderNamespace Microsoft.Network
```